# Accessing printer on different network

Tags: networking, router

I have two fibre broadband connections into my house from 2 ISP's

Connection A and Connection B - Both have their own ISP supplied routers with both WiFi and Ethernet. (Router A and Router B)

I have an HP Envy 6200 printer.

Most of the "household" devices (Plex Server, Kids Laptops, TV's, tablets etc...) are connected via WiFi to Router A.

My main office machine is connected via Ethernet to Router B.  The HP printer is also connected (via WiFi) to Router B.

How can I enable it so all the devices connected to Router A can print to the printer on Router B ?

Any ideas would be much appreciated - Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of multiple ways to solve this. Solutions requiring to physical changes (cables) in your topology:

- Forward the printers port on Router B to the router and use the public IP address of Router B in your LAN behind router A. This is probably not the best idea depending on the authentication support of your printer and only works if youre not behind CG-NAT!
- Maybe you can tunnel the printer into the network behind router A e.g. using VPN.

Solutions requiring changes to your topology:

- You could connect a ethernet cable to some ethernet port (e.g. ethX) of router A and make sure that it terminates in LAN of router B (on the router, a switch next to the printer or so). Then you would just need a routing table entry in router A which would make sure that interface ethX is used for the IP address of the printer. Maybe not the cleanest solution since you would have to make sure that different subnets are used in both networks.
- Depending on the reason why you have two upstream ISPs you could join both networks and use only one router. If fail-safety is your concern you could configure both ISP links as upstream interfaces. If your concern is separation of both areas my advice is that you could do two VLANs, one for home and one for your office. The printer would be tagged for both VLANs. This would be quite a clean solution but would require some additional hardware & cabling.
- If your printer happens to have two interfaces (e.g. LAN1, LAN2 or LAN1, WLAN1) you can use each interface for one network. I'm guessing you don't have this option.

Comment: Part of the problem is that I will be using ISP routers so not many options.

Main reason for two ISP's is that bandwidth is saturated with the kids devices and I work from home.

Router B is dedicated to office connection.

TBH main use of the printer is the kids on A (I would still like access to it)

Possible solution :

Connect the printer via WiFi to A - Everyone on A can access it.

In my main rig connect via Ethernet to B for my main tasks (set to a higher priority in Windows).  Connect at the same time to A via WiFi so I have access to the printer - Is that doable ?

Comment: Yes that would correspond to that last option outlined above and I think it should work.

Comment: It might also be worth to check if your router A actually doesnt support it I saw this feature present on many low-end routers. Also, you could technically add a second router A2 if you can live with double NAT. Finally, depending on your printer it might support some cloud service for printing over the internet?